# Creating a light button border

Tags: android, button

I want create in button with light button border with little 3D shade on edges like this
[image]

Comment: Use a **9 patch** for the Button's background.

Answer (score 1):

create an **xml** in your **drawable**

```
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <layer-list>
        <item android:right="2dp" android:top="2dp">
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="0dp" />
                <solid android:color="#A09D9D" 
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp">
            <shape>
                <gradient android:angle="270" 
                    android:endColor="@color/white"
                     android:startColor="@color/white" />
                <stroke
                    android:width="0.5dp" 
                    android:color="#CBCBC9" />
                <corners 
                    android:radius="0dp" />

            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>

</selector>
```

and use this xml as your button background

Answer (score 0):

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >

       <solid android:color="@color/white"  />

      <stroke android:width="1dip"  android:color="@color/gray"> 

           </stroke>
    </shape>
```

Set this Xml on background